# Disable source map in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, source-maps, jquery-source-map

I have problem with jquery-1.10.2.min.map -- it is downloading about 19-20sec:
http://c2n.me/3zJUwuV

Only IE is trying to load this file, and i cant find how to disable it.

I've tried to delete .map-file from its folder, and I of course get 404, but it spends the same 19-20sec.

There are many ways in internet how to disable source map in chrome, firefox, etc., but no one about IE.
Is it possible? And how?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

You can disable source maps in the IE 11 Developer Tools Debugger using the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+M or by clicking the icon with the tooltip "Load the sources mapped to this generated file". The icon is located to the right in the tab strip for the Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Open edit: jquery.min.js
 2. Remove the following comment //@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map
 3. Save the file
```

Now the Browser should not request the source map file anymore.

Newer versions of JQuery seems to have disable source map by default:

> As of jQuery 1.11.0/2.1.0 the //# sourceMappingURL comment is not
> included in the compressed file.

Ref: https://jquery.com/download/